# Nullable object must have a value in join tables query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have three tables `TableTeam`, `TableUser` and `TableLink`. I want to join them to get a list.

```
var teams = _db.TableTeam;
var users = _db.TableUser;
var managerIds = teams.Select(x=>x.ManagerId).ToList();
var list = (from user in _db.TableUser
        where user.EndDate == null && user.ManagerId != null && managerIds.Contains(user.ManagerId.Value)
        let r = _db.TableLink.FirstOrDefault(l => l.ProjectId == projectId && l.UserId  == user.UserId)
        let t = _db.TableTeam.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ManagerId == user.ManagerId)
        select new MyDto
        {
            ProjectId = projectId,
            UserId = user.UserId,
            IsAssigned = r.AssignedId > 0 ?true : false,
            AssignedId = r.AssignedId,
            Percent = r.Percent.HasValue ? (r.Percent.Value).ToString() + "%": ""
        }).GroupBy(d => d.UserId).ToList();
```

For the table `TableLink`, the corresponding dataSet class in entity framework is:

```
public LinkDto
{
   public int AssignedId {get;set;}
   public short ProjectId {get;set;}
   public short UserId {get;set;}
   public decimal? Percent {get;set;}
   // ...
}
```

However I got the error:

> Nullable object must have a value

I think that it may be caused by `decimal? Percent`. But not sure how to fix it. Also I can use the store d procedure as well, which means if you can solve it by SQL query, that is also great.

Comment: `r.Percent.Value ? (r.Percent.Value).ToString() + "%": ""` typo? [this would not even compile as `r.Percent.Value` is not `bool`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZeMdR)

Comment: @Selvin `r.Precent` is `decimal?` so I assume he meant `r.Percent.HasValue`.

Comment: You are right, typo. Fixed.

Comment: You have 'r = ... FirstOrDefault()` which implies sometimes `r` could be `null` in which case referencing `r.anyfield` would be an exception. If `r` can't be `null`, use `First()` or `Single()` instead. Which LINQ is this? LINQ to EF 6/EF Core 2.0/EF Core 2.1/EF Core 3.x/SQL?

Comment: linq to EF CORE 2.1

Comment: If I use `First()`, I got another error, `Sequence contains no elements`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I have to move `let` codes before `where` clause then add the condition to `where`.

Such as

```
var list = (from user in _db.TableUser
    let r = _db.TableLink.FirstOrDefault(l => l.ProjectId == projectId && l.UserId  == user.UserId)
    let t = _db.TableTeam.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ManagerId == user.ManagerId)
    where user.EndDate == null && user.ManagerId != null && managerIds.Contains(user.ManagerId.Value) 
    && r != null && t != null
    select new MyDto
    {
        ProjectId = projectId,
        UserId = user.UserId,
        IsAssigned = r.AssignedId > 0 ?true : false,
        AssignedId = r.AssignedId,
        Percent = r.Percent.HasValue ? (r.Percent.Value).ToString() + "%": ""
    }).GroupBy(d => d.UserId).ToList();
```